# How to convert an object with dict shape in a dict or DataFrame (Python)

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I'm working with two IMUs, in order to obtain an angle. The case is that when I receive the data, it has a formart like this:

```
{heading : 0.002, pitch : 0.000, roll : -0.000, yaw : 0.000}
```

In this format, the keys values are not strings, and all it is only one object. For that, when I have some objects of this kind, If I make a list with all of them and then make a DataFrame from the list, the result is

```
                          0
0    {heading : 0.002, pitch : 0.000, roll : 0.000,...
1    {heading : 0.002, pitch : 0.000, roll : 0.000,...
2    {heading : 0.000, pitch : 0.000, roll : 0.000,...
3    {heading : 0.002, pitch : 0.000, roll : 0.000,...
4    {heading : 0.002, pitch : 0.000, roll : 0.000,...
..                                                 ...
129  {heading : 0.002, pitch : 0.000, roll : 0.000,...
130  {heading : 0.002, pitch : 0.000, roll : 0.000,...
131  {heading : 0.002, pitch : 0.000, roll : 0.000,...
132  {heading : 0.002, pitch : 0.000, roll : 0.000,...
133  {heading : 0.002, pitch : 0.000, roll : 0.000,...
```

and I would like obtain something like this:

```
    heading    pitch     roll   yaw
0    value     value     value  value
1    value     value     value  value
2    value     value     value  value
```

Someone can help me? Thanks!

Comment: The question is not clear itself because you created some kind of dictionary structure with invalid key values that are neither string not objects as you have not provided any information on how these objects get created. So, it has been unclear if you can make a string out of this pseudo dict structure you provided.

Comment: I suggest you shall force the output that provides you such pseudo dict to make valid key values as strings and provide you with json formatted data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [hjson](https://pypi.org/project/hjson/) module

```
import hjson
data = ['{heading : 0.002, pitch : 0.000, roll : -0.000, yaw : 0.000}',
        '{heading : 0.001, pitch : 0.003, roll : -0.000, yaw : 0.005}']
new_data = [hjson.loads(d) for d in data]
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(new_data)


    heading     pitch   roll    yaw
0   0.002       0.000   0       0.000
1   0.001       0.003   0       0.005
```

Comment: Thanks, im going to test it

Comment: Python itself also has the `json` module as a built-in that doesn't require a `pip install`: [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load)

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a [`pd.read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) method.

From the docs:

```
>>> df.to_json(orient='records')
'[{"col 1":"a","col 2":"b"},{"col 1":"c","col 2":"d"}]'
>>> pd.read_json(_, orient='records')
  col 1 col 2
0     a     b
1     c     d
```